# Incomplete Item's title in index page

Tags: php, title

sorry for my bad english :)
In index page, in foreach circle, title do not load completely (some last character will lost-irregular), specially for arabic character.

```
<?php foreach($this->items as $item) { ?>   <?php echo $item; >   <?php } ?>
```

but in each item single page, Title load completely.

```
<?php echo $this->item['name']; ?>
```

where is the problem?

structure: CMV PHP

===
for example:

You should provide some sample data

print:

You should provide some sample data

or:

You should provide some sample data. What does loo

print:

You should provide some sample

or:

POLAROGRAPHIC DETERMINATION OF CR (VI) IN ENVIRONM

print:

POLAROGRAPHIC DETERMINATION OF CR

or:

تاریخچه کمومتریکس روشهای ورود داده، روش

print:

تاریخچه ک

or:

This is a sample title test, any thing is ok

print:

This is a sample title test, any

Comment: You should provide some sample data. What does it look like in your database and what does it look like when it is displayed?

Comment: pls post a dump of $this->items

Comment: Assuming a HTML page as output, are the texts in the `$this->item` array already HTML-encoded?